# Can I get metadata of generic type in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata

I have a decorated model class:

```
@Api('payments/deposit')
export class DepositsModel {
  public id: number;
  public created_at: Date;
  ...
```

In angular component constructor I'm injecting data service pointing to use my model class:

```
...
public constructor( 
  private $api: GridApiService<DepositsModel>
...
) {
  this.service = new GridService($api);
  ...
}
...
```

So, my cool component has a cool service, witch knows the type of data it work with...

Should know..

But how I can to get my model's metadata in my GridApiService? I've tried:

```
@Injectable()
export class GridApiService<T>{
  constructor(
    $http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    let api = Reflect.getMetadata('Api', T);
  }
```

And got  **Error message: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**

UPDATE

Can you advice me another way to pass initialization data to my GridApiService, witch should be injected through DI, not created with new keyword?

Answer (score 7):

TypeScript types don't exist at runtime, with the exception of those that can be emitted as metadata via class decorators. Generic types [cannot be emitted](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3015) and don't exist for Angular DI. `GridApiService<DepositsModel>` doesn't matter for anything but type checking.

The connection between `GridApiService` and a `DepositsModel` should be expressed with class design, for example inheritance:

```
class DepositsGridApiService extends GridApiService {
  Model = DepositsModel;
}
```

Comment: Yea, but I was looking the way to not generate a hord of services but have universal one...

Comment: You have to proceed from the capabilites of the framework, and the framework doesn't offer anything like that. If there can be more than one kind of GridApiService<T> per injector, you'll have to either subclass it or inject factory function or wrapper class that is instantiated with T argument. This is potential XY problem, and the preferred solution may differ from what you're trying to do. And AOT will impose some limitations, too.

Comment: should be accepted as an asnwer I think. TypeScripts generic parameters are useful for type cheking in design time, nothing more than a helper for editor in deed.

Comment: This answer was helpful, it confirmed what I'm seeing which is that generics are not available at runtime using reflection.