# Typescript generic class

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have a typescript class (in angular 5) and i am trying to make it working but i have some annoying issues.

The class:

```
export abstract class TableComponentBase<TModel extends DomainModel<TModel>, TDialog extends DialogBase<TModel>>
extends PageComponent {
```

My method:

```
    onCreate() {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TDialog, {
  data: {
    buttonText: "Létrehozás",
    title: "Új záróvizsga létrehozása",
    element: new TModel()//FinalExam.createEmpty()
  }
});
```

The problem is with the "TDialog" which is not acceptable for dialog.open. How could i fix this? And i also trying to figure out how could i initialize a new TModel (like in c# with the new()).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This isn't possible. TypeScript's type system is fully erased. Trying to apply the pattern that you use in C# is therefore impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get metadata of generic type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167201/can-i-get-metadata-of-generic-type-in-typescript)